How can I use foreignId in Laravel with camelCase?
I have a table User, which has an id. In another table (AdminUser), I want to reference it, but with camelCase convention.
However, Laravel doesn't convert that and/or recognize the user table, so it returns always null when asking for the user from the other table.
I am experimenting with something, so the table layout User and AdminUser might be weird, but that is not the point of the question.
Here is the AdminUser table:
Schema::create('AdminUser', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->foreign('userId');
    $table->integer('pin');
    $table->string('passcode');
    $table->timestamp('updatedAt');
    $table->timestamp('createdAt');
});

Here is the User table:
Schema::create('User', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('username');
    $table->string('password');
    $table->enum('role', ['ADMIN', 'USER'])->default('USER');
    $table->string('loginToken')->nullable();
    $table->rememberToken()->nullable();
    $table->renameColumn('remember_token', 'rememberToken');
    $table->timestamp('createdAt');
    $table->timestamp('updatedAt');
});

If I reference it with user_id in the AdminUser table, it is working properly, but I would like to find out how to use camelCase foreign keys.

Why are you going against Laravel conventions? Why make your life harder? Why not follow, I would say, database standards (does not even care if it is Laravel or not), use snake_case. Could you add more info on why you are doing this?

I had a competition task, where everything was with either PascalCase (table names) or camelCase for column names. It was annoying, because that's not the convention I am used to. So I'm trying to prepare myself with knowing how to change convention if I encounter again such a task

Oh, okay, it makes sense, I just wanted to know what exact problem you were trying to solve, thank  you

No worries, I wouldn't do such things as I have no issues with the default convention, I just have to be familiar with the methods how to change it

Solution found
All I had to do, is to add some modifications into the foreignId function.
It looks like this now:
$table->foreignId('userId')->references('id')->on('user');

And I also had to slightly modify the relationship as well:
public function user(): \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'userId');
}

